# How can I access the attributes of an element cloned via jquery within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to permit my users to dynamically create new categories and then branches and sub-branches within categories. To facilitate this I've built an html table that contains multiple nested tables. Each nested table is surrounded by its own div. The base category displays on the left and branches and sub-branches grow out to the right.

To allow the user to create the branches I call jquery clone() within a javascript function. Like this:

```
function elementCopy(targetTable, targetDiv)
{        
  var clone = $('.' + targetTable).clone(true).appendTo($("." + targetDiv));     
}
```

This creates the requested clone and places it in the correct table. But I have not discovered how to access the clone's attributes to edit them.

In a previous iteration of this functionality, I called jquery clone() from within document.ready().

```
$('button[name="newTasks"]').click(function()
    {                        
        //Create the cloned block and keep the event listener so the     newly displayed plus icon 
        // also creates a new block.
        var clone = $(".tasksTable").eq(0).clone(true).appendTo(".tasksDiv"); 

        //
        clone.find( ".tasksTable" ).attr('name', 'Tasks' + '_' + countTaskBlocks);                        
     });
```

I abandoned this iteration because I was unable to send parameters to the document.ready() version. Without the parameters, I could not position the clone within its proper table and sub-table. However, this version DID allow me to edit the clone's attributes.

This line edits all of the elements with the same class name:

```
$('.' + targetTable).attr('class', 'tasksTable' + '_' + countTaskBlocks);
```

How can I edit the 'name', 'id', and 'class' attributes of the specific clone created in the call to 'elementCopy' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery methods are chainable, so you can do something like this.

```
function elementCopy( targetTable, targetDiv ) {
    var clone = $( '.' + targetTable )
        .clone( true )
        .appendTo( $( "." + targetDiv ) )
        .attr( {
            'name':  'Tasks' + '_' + countTaskBlocks,
            'id':    'Tasks' + '_' + countTaskBlocks,
            'class': 'Tasks' + '_' + countTaskBlocks
        } );
    return clone;
}
```

Check out the demo below.

```js
$('a').clone( true ).appendTo( $('body') ).attr( { 'class': 'Goodbye', 'href': 'http://www.example.com' } );
```

```css
a::before { margin-right: .5em; content: attr(href); } a::after { margin-left: .5em; content: attr(class); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="hello" href="#">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search the children of the DIV you appended the clone to by the class name of the element you cloned.